# Why is +3 h another output as +3 hours?

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I am writing a small Time calculation. It should always add 3h to a given time.

But if i do `"+3 h"` in the method `strtotime()` in php it will output another value. So I wonder why `"+3 hours"` will work. Can somebody explain me why?

My php version is: `7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4`

```php
$date = "2019-05-04 15:00"; //format is Y-m-d H:i
$out = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("+3 h", strtotime($date)));
echo $out; //out = 2019-05-04 14:00

$date = "2019-05-04 15:00"; //format is Y-m-d H:i
$out = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("+3 hours", strtotime($date)));
echo $out; //out = 2019-05-04 18:00
```

This is a test example code from me. And `$date` is a different value every 15min.

*PS: this is my first question on stackoverflow - Hello World :D*

Comment: Welcome! I think you simply have to use `+3 hours` because that what the unit is called in [the list](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)? Just wondering: Are you trying to compensate for a timezone? In that case you should use [timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php).

Comment: i won't compensate my timezone a want the time after an action in 3 hours. its only a example code and `$date` canges every 15min.

Comment: `* ... i want the time ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) -  Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp**

You need to use `hour` OR `hours`. Similar for days you can use `day` or `days`.

```
$date = "2019-05-04 15:00"; //format is Y-m-d H:i
$out = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("+3 h", strtotime($date)));
echo $out; //out = 2019-05-04 12:00
```

The output is showing `2019-05-04 12:00` not `2019-05-04 14:00`.

It seems when you put the wrong format; ike `+3 h`, it's just subtracting that from the original time

Comment: do you've tested that: `//out = 2019-05-04 12:00`? Because the output at me is `2019-05-04 14:00`. That's why i wonder O.o

Comment: And your second sentence is wrong too because this (at me):
https://pastebin.com/dsUKUCPV

Comment: @PlayerSchark yes i have tested it on my machine

Comment: @PlayerSchark PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1 both displaying 2019-05-04 12:00 command line

Comment: weird O.o maybe there's a wrong setting in my config file of php